# How to become proficient using the JWST pipeline?

Tags: james-webb-space-telescope, data-pipeline

I am trying to obtain proficiency in reviewing and analyzing JWST data. To that end, I have installed python jdaviz environment and files and JWST python environment and files. I am tinkering with some of the apps and example data. I realize is it several months before any real data can be obtained but I'd like to develop some proficiency during the shakedown period.

I wish to find a description of the final operational data acquisition pipeline steps for JWST. There are descriptions of a calibration reference (CRDS) data pipeline but I don't know if that is only for initial calibration or is that for the final data flow.

Could someone point me to the final data pipeline scheme and needed software as well as to how to arrive at it from the initial efforts at startup and calibration.

I need some technical detail - not layman level-  but I am also not an analytical astronomer either, just a broken-down engineer.

Comment: [(temporarily) cross-posted in Space SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57778/12102) Double posting is faster but not the recommended way. Now that it's done, it's best to delete the copy over in Space SE to prevent answer fragmentation. Migration has the benefit that the votes there would be carried over here. so you could still delete this and wait for the migration if you like. Either way, in the end only one copy of a question should be available for answers to be posted. *Thanks!*

Comment: Now that we have the first real data, I'm interested in worked examples. Can anyone answer [Webb data pipeline explanations e.g. using the first five images? - Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50018/webb-data-pipeline-explanations-e-g-using-the-first-five-images)?

Answer (score 8):

The Space Telescope Science Institute ran a series of ["JWebbinars"](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/science-execution/jwebbinars) in 2021 for which registration is closed but the materials and slides are available from the link above (unfold the "Materials and Videos" section further down the page).

The first JWebbinar talks about the 'Pipeline Information and Data Products' and the second presentation that is linked to is entitled [Intro to Pipeline Stages](https://stsci.app.box.com/s/fgxy3y0uzqf6540ey0ym2slzi3uyh6ar) so hopefully this will give you some info to get started.

Additional: Data from the first JWST released images will be made available through [MAST](https://mast.stsci.edu) starting from 2022 July 13 11am EDT as detailed in [this news item](https://www.stsci.edu/contents/news/jwst/2022/accessing-jwst-science-data-after-the-end-of-commissioning).

Comment: These webinars look very promising.  I will start going through them.  See if I can put my data pipeline together

Comment: The webinars reference provided above solves my query.  Only caveat is that NASA said the software in these webibars might not be final so one needs to keep looking for new addons or changes.  Gives many, many hours of work for me to get up to speed.  Starts with using older astropy routines and then shows how new jwst routines add features and functionality.

Comment: Some tweaks to the pipeline will likely be needed once the instruments are cooled down and the commissioning data are taken and pushed through the pipeline. It's unlikely, given the amount of on-ground testing, that this would produce major changes in the form of new pipeline stages or different output but it's possible. Pipelines are always being improved; look at the HST instrument or [Kepler/K2 pipeline notes](https://keplergo.github.io/KeplerScienceWebsite/k2-pipeline-release-notes.html).

Comment: Also of possible interest: there is a virtual [JWST Town Hall](https://www.stsci.edu/contents/events/jwst/2022/january/jwst-town-hall) happening on Fri Jan 28 12:00pm EST which would have happened during the annual American Astronomical Society meeting but was postponed when the AAS meeting was cancelled due to COVID/Omicron