# Webb data pipeline explanations e.g. using the first five images?

Tags: james-webb-space-telescope, data-pipeline

The [first 5 stunning results](https://webbtelescope.org/resource-gallery/images) from the [Webb Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) are now available!
And the raw data is available for them, e.g. via [bulk download scripts](https://outerspace.stsci.edu/display/MASTDATA/JWST+AWS+Bulk+Download+Scripts) or via the [Mikulski Archive for Space Telescopes (MAST) Portal](https://mast.stsci.edu/portal/Mashup/Clients/Mast/Portal.html).

So the initial data [pipelines](https://jwst-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwst/introduction.html) are now in operation.

Are there any detailed walk-thrus of how the raw data was processed for any of the images or analyses that have been reported? I'd love something that showed how the rawest data looked, then how the many steps functioned to subtract the dark field, apply calibrations, association steps to combine sometimes thousands of observations into a final image and so-on. That would help people appreciate the intricate process involved in this stunning achievement, which relies on computer scientists, as well as rocket scientists, engineers, artists, bureaucrats and of course astronomers.

After all, thousands of datasets have already been made made available to the public and continue to arrive via the [Director’s Discretionary Early Release Science Programs](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/science-execution/approved-ers-programs) and other programs with no exclusive access for the proposers, and preprints are already showing up from researchers accessing the public archive. The floodgates are open, and the opportunity to drill down into how this works is nearly unprecedented.

*Update:* Note that the pipeline I'm talking about goes from raw stage 0 data to the calibrated stage 3 results. There is a separate process for taking monochrome stage 3 results and combining them to get color images, and of course tons more kinds of later combinations and analyses. This question is about the initial Webb pipeline itself.

Comment: This recent preprint fills in some of the gaps, though not with quite the approach I have in mind: [\[2207.13067\] The JWST Early Release Observations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.13067)

Answer (score 5):

Look at link below from this site:  jwst data analysis pipeline -- how to become proficient

It has good ref to the procedures and needed software.

It looks like you are looking for, essentially, an "example" step by step walkthrough using a new webb data set that you can run along with the procedures, I have not seen that.

There is a youtube vide that shows how to procure a dataset, process, and view an image, though.  See:

hope this gives something to get started,      tom kosvic

Comment: Sorry about the pic.  When I pasted youtube ref in it inswerted the picture.The ref is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVuonz26P0w&t=151s

Comment: Thanks. I had seen much of this. What I'm looking for is a specific example to get a sense for how the pieces fit together in the initial pipeline from stage 0 to stage 3. The video here is great fun, but it describes the artistic process of combining the stage 3 results that come out of the pipeline, not now those stage 3 results themselves were produced. The author of the video doesn't even understand the calibration results that come out of the pipeline.